# I get an Intellisence "no instence of overload function rotate() matches the argument list. How can i resolve

Tags: c++, glm-math

I get an Intellisence "no instence of overload `function rotate()` matches the argument list. argument list are (float ,float ,float float)."
I already provide the float value arguments.

get error on rotate function.

how can i resolve? plz help me...

```
for (int i = 1;i<10;i++)
    {

        planets[i].self_angle += planets[i].self_rotation_step*delta;

        planets[i].sun_angle += planets[i].sun_rotation_step*delta*ratios[i - 1];

        trans_to_planet_postion = translate(planets[i].Position);
        scaleplanet = scale(planets[i].Scale);
        planet_self_rotation = rotate(planets[i].self_angle, 0.0f, planets[i].self_angle, 1.0f);
        rotate_around_sun = rotate(planets[i].sun_angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        ModelMatrix = rotate_around_sun *trans_to_planet_postion *planet_self_rotation*scaleplanet;
        planets[i].modelmatrix = ModelMatrix;
        MVP = ProjectionMatrix*ViewMatrix*ModelMatrix;
        planets[i].mvp = MVP;
    }
```

Here is the error message...

> Error C2780   'glm::mat<4,4,T,Q> glm::rotate(const glm::mat<4,4,T,Q>
>   &,T,const glm::vec<4,T,Q> &)': expects 3 arguments - 4 provided

Comment: What `rotate` function are you trying to call?

Comment: i create a project in opengl of desgin a solar system. in this project i want to rotate the planets etc.

Comment: You *do* have created a `rotate` function that takes the argument you provide? Or are you supposed to use some other `rotate` function (like `glm::rotate`)?

Comment: i use a glm graphics library.

Comment: Have you included `<glm/gtx/transform.hpp>`? The default rotate function does take three arguments only.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you meant to pass in a rotation axis vector to the [two-parameter rotate override](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00779.html#gaf599be4c0e9d99be1f9cddba79b6018b)

In which case you should be saying

```
rotate_around_sun = rotate(planets[i].sun_angle, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```